# Rotate object to mouse direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this script, that already works
I,m using leanFinger

```
    var c = Camera.main;
    var center = rb.position;
    var lastPos = _finger.GetWorldPosition(c.transform.position.y, c);
    var lastDelta = Vector3.Distance(center, lastPos);

    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lastPos.x, lastPos.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, angle - initialRotation, 0));
```

The problem is that my object is rotating in absolute angles, so if it is already rotated, there is a unwanted rotation. I want it to take an initialRotation value, but i don't know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform.rotation to access the current rotation of your object: [Transform.rotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html)

You could also use this method for convenience: [Transform.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)

Simple JS example:

```
public var target : Transform;

function Update ()
{
    transform.LookAt(target);
}
```

Comment: With this approach, if the object is already rotated, that rotation will be ignored